# How can I go back from fragment 2 to fragment 1 ? as shown in the picture

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Fragment 1 is opened by navigation drawer and fragment 2 is opened by fragment  1 now I want to go back from fragment 2 to fragment 1 with back button as shown in picture and wanna hide drawer icon from fragment 2

[image]

Comment: Use Android Navigation Drawer - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I am already using drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding Activity and then first call activity from previous fragment then call your desired fragment in activity and finally add back button on the activity.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
       /* ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.header);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); */
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Smart Take Away");
      //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }
     //   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            try {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                DetailedListFragment fragment = new DetailedListFragment();
            //    fragment.setArguments(extras);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailfragment, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a click or swipe event

get the instance of your second fragment

```
SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, fragment).commit();
```